# Javascript Datetime Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datetime

I've been a programmer for only a few months, and I'm super new at Javascript, so help me out if there's a simpler way. I'm creating a drop down of months and a textbox of year. 
Is there a better way to do my month select box? 
And how can I format my date to yyyy-mm-dd?
Thanks!

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <select id="month">
                <option value="0">January</option>
                <option value="1">February</option>
                <option value="2">March</option>
                <option value="3">April</option>
                <option value="4">May</option>
                <option value="5">June</option>
                <option value="6">July</option>
                <option value="7">August</option>
                <option value="8">September</option>
                <option value="9">October</option>
                <option value="10">November</option>
                <option value="11">December</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="year">Year:</label>
            <input type="text" id="year" value=""/>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var budget_start_date = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var budget_end_date;
            $('#start_date').val(budget_start_date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
            $('#end_date').val(budget_end_date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: you can use jQuery UI datepicker, it has a method for that: $.datepicker.formatDate

Comment: Consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to re-invent the wheel in this one, you are already using jQuery so you might as well use [jQuery Date Picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), after you load the references you get a full functional calendar by doing `$('#yourDateField').datepicker()`

About the format part, you could use [DataJS](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs), then the format is simple as `dt.toString('dd-MM-yyyy')`

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of the date formatting:

```
/**
 * Default format：yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss
 * @param string stamp Time in milliseconds
 * @param string format Your desired format
 * @param boolean zero With zero-prefix or not
 */
function format(timestamp, format, zero){
    var stamp = Number(timestamp),
        date = new Date(stamp), formatDate,
        f = format ? format : "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss",
        _d = (zero === undefined) ? l.format.zero : function(s){return s;};

    var year = _d(date.getFullYear()),
        month = _d(date.getMonth() + 1),
        day = _d(date.getDate()),
        hour = _d(date.getHours()),
        minute = _d(date.getMinutes()),
        second = _d(date.getSeconds());

    formatDate = f.replace(/yyyy/i, year).replace(/mm/i, month).replace(/dd/i, day)
                .replace(/hh/i, hour).replace(/ii/i, minute).replace(/ss/i, second);
    return formatDate;
},
```